# Running methods in the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

At the begging I have write very general topic, even if I know about thread and proccess, but I don't know which of these both will be better for my case.

Ok, so.. code:

```
class Proces(object):
[...]

def Obsluz(self):
    proces = LRU(self.sekwencja, int(self.przydzielone_ramki))
    proces.Symulacja("T")
    #.thread.join()
def Threads(self):
        thread = Thread(target = self.Obsluz)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

and running that code :

```
for lru in self.lru_procesy:
        lru.Watek()
```

What I want achieve is running at the same time method Obsluz several times with different params(which are taking from Proces.attributes). It's random number how many will be proces object. It can be 10/20/30 ect.

My code above is not running like I want to, because each thread is ending one by one(because of .join()). Is it possible to running these at the same time?

thank you!

Comment: Just a general notice: you should probably use English variable names, instead using your native language, that way it's easier for everyone to read your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just starting one worker and immediately waiting for it to finish.

To spawn several worker threads and wait for them all to finish use something like this:

```
  workers = []
  for wid in range(nworkers):
    w = Thread(target = dowork, args = ...)
    w.start()
    workers.append(w)
  # join all of the workers
  for w in workers: w.join()
  print "All done!"
```